# How can I connect to the internet using usb via gsm modem?

Tags: internet, usb-modem, nokia

I want to connect to internet with GSM of my nokia6120 phone and want to do it via cable.

how can I do it?

Comment: It's called tethering, and do be sure your phone provider allows it, and be really sure you understand how much (extra) it will cost.

Answer (score 1):

First connect your Nokia Phone to your PC with PC Suite Mode . Then look at the top panel , Rightside . You will find some symbol like network . click there .

you will find a name like creating a new connection at the area of mobile broadband . click it .

then it will ask your Country and operator and the access-point name .give them as it asks and then save it . then again you click same network applet on the panel . it will show connections like in image. click at connection you have created and it will connect:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did this but the item "New Mobile broadband...." does not appeared.